# Forms authentication , logged time , get logged username from crypted cookie in the sqldatasource parameter source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sqldatasource and a gridview.
I'm using forms authentication.

After the user logged in , I'm crypting his name

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
      string cookiestr;
      HttpCookie ck;
      tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUserName.text, DateTime.Now, 
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, false);
      cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
      ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
      ck.Expires=tkt.Expiration;    
      ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath; 
      Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

In the redirected page I need to set in the sqldatasource , where -> parameter source : cookie

- BUT,
- 1.I don't know the cookie name because as I can see it doesn't have one.
- 2.Since the cookie was crypted , the sqldatasource must use the decrypted cookie..well..I'm not sure what to do in order to use the username string.

All in all , I'm trying to crypt his name and in the redirected page to use the logged user name in  a sqldatasource where condition . I can do this if I Don't crypt the cookie but..since the cookie can be edited..I don't want ppl to edit cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans 1. The default name of the FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName is ".ASPXAUTH".
 But if you wish over write the name then you will have to do it in the config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    name=".NEW_COOKIE_NAME" />
</authentication>
```